# Not able to use for loop values with 01,02,03,...,97,98,99

Tags: php, for-loop

i would like to use for loop with values starts from 01, 02, 03 . . ., 98, 99.

How to do this?

```
<?php .
    $ticketNum = 82891521;
    for ($i=1; $i<100; $i++)
    {   
     echo "<a href='#'>$ticketNum$i</a>".' | ';
    }
?>
```

Expected Output:

```
8289152100
8289152101
8289152102
8289152103
...
...
...
8289152199
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$ticketNum = 82891521;
$newNum=$ticketNum*100;

for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++)
{   
  echo ($newNum+$i);
}
```

<kbd>**[`IDEONE`](https://ideone.com/RQo0kA)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks  Anik Islam Abhi.. it works.. :-)

Comment: Abhi.. now i have a problem.. when i add a <a href> tag it shows result as 
(8289152200+0)
(8289152200+1)
(8289152200+2)
(8289152200+3)

How to add <a href="url">tag?

Comment: @DineshDiNu check this https://ideone.com/RQo0kA

Comment: Abhi i know how to use anchor tag. now my problem is inside anchor i need a ticket value. see the out put link..
 http://#/ticket/(8289152100+0)
 http://#/ticket/(8289152100+1)
 http://#/ticket/(8289152100+2)
 http://#/ticket/(8289152100+4)

Comment: now check @DineshDiNu https://ideone.com/RQo0kA

Comment: Thanks Anik Islam Abhi.. it works great.. now i have fixed all the issues.. thanks again..

Comment: @DineshDiNu you are welcome :) Don't forget to give upvote if you didn't give :)